# The Cauchy problem associated with $u_t^\epsilon + H(x,t,u^\epsilon,\nabla u^\epsilon) = \epsilon\Delta u^\epsilon$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde

Consider the initial value problem $$\begin{cases} u_t^\epsilon + H(x,t,u^\epsilon,\nabla_x u^\epsilon) = \epsilon\Delta_x u^\epsilon & \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^n \times (0,\infty)\\ u^\epsilon = g &\text{ in } \mathbb{R}^n \times \{t= 0\}\end{cases}, $$ for $\epsilon>0$.

> Can you point out one (some) reference(s) for a complete proof of a theorem roughly to the effect that, under adequate hypothesis on $H$ and $g$, this Cauchy problem admits a unique $C^{2,1}(\mathbb{R}^n \times [0,\infty))$ solution (that is $C^2$ with respect to $x$ and $C^1$ with respect to $t$)?

Comment: See Sect. 6 of the Crandall, Ishii, Lions survey http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1992-27-01/S0273-0979-1992-00266-5/S0273-0979-1992-00266-5.pdf

Comment: For $\epsilon>0$  this is a quasilinear parabolic equation   and  existence for such  equations is known under certain conditions on $H$ (stronger than continuity).  Theorem 6.5  in the above survey  gives a sufficient  condition  for convergence.

Comment: Crandall, Michael G.; Lions, Pierre-Louis
Viscosity solutions of Hamilton-Jacobi equations. 
Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 277 (1983), no. 1, 1–42.

Comment: Read the survey of Crandall Lions and Ishii  and check the references there

Comment: The statement you want is not true. Consider the linear case $H=H(x,t)$. For some continuous functions  $H$ the bounded solution does not belong to the class $C^{2,1}_{x,t}(\mathbb{R}^n \times \{t>0\})$.

Comment: @Andrew Obviously, we need several hypotheses on $H$ and $g$, which, I think, should not be much different from the ones that are commonly used to prove the uniqueness of viscosity solutions for Hamilton-Jacobi equations.